Submenús con submenús anidados #wordpress #wp_get_nav_menu_items
Tengo este código y por mas que pruebo no hayo la solución
// Este método lo tengo en una clase llamada Helpers.php

public static function childMenu( $menuArray, $parentId ): mixed {
     $childMenus = [];

     if ( ! empty( $menuArray ) && is_array( $menuArray ) ) {
         foreach ($menuArray as $menu) {
            if ( intval( $menu->menu_item_parent ) === $parentId ) {
                    array_push( $childMenus, $menu );
            }
         }
     }
        return $childMenus;
}
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Y lo mando a llamar en este archivo menu.php

$locMenuName = get_nav_menu_locations()['kiss-menu-top'];
$menuItems   = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $locMenuName );


    if ( ! empty( $menuItems ) && is_array( $menuItems ) ) {
        foreach ($menuItems as $menItem){
            if ( ! $menItem->menu_item_parent ) {
                $childMenuItems = Helpers::childMenu( $menuItems, $menItem->ID );
                $hasChildren = ! empty( $childMenuItems ) && is_array( $childMenuItems );
                if ( ! $hasChildren ) {
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $menItem->url ) ?>" class="flex items-center justify-between px-3 shadow  group-hover:[&_svg]:rotate-90 w-full p-2 text-xl text-white bg-[#03222e] shadow-black">
                        <?php echo esc_html( $menItem->title ) ; ?>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <div class="group">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $menItem->url ) ?>" class="flex items-center justify-between px-3 shadow  group-hover:[&_svg]:rotate-90 w-full p-2 text-xl text-white bg-[#03222e] shadow-black">
                            <?php echo esc_html( $menItem->title ) ; ?>
                            <span>
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="block size-6 hover:text-orange-500 drop-shadow-lg ">
                                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="m8.25 4.5 7.5 7.5-7.5 7.5" />
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="z-50 hidden gap-1 text-xl p-1 mt-1 text-gray-800 bg-[#2c1010] shadow shadow-black group-hover:flex  group-hover:flex-col ">
                            <?php
                            foreach ($childMenuItems as $childMenu) {
                                ?>

                                <a class="g border-b border-slate-40 text-[#0dda51] p-1 px-3" href="<?php echo esc_url( $childMenu->url );?>">
                                    <?php echo esc_html( $childMenu->title );?>
                                </a> 
                                <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                
            }

            ?>
            
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        ?>
        <div class="p-4 text-2xl text-center rounded-md shadow bg-indigo-950 shadow-black">
            <?php echo "No hay menú aun ... "; ?> 
        </div> 
        <?php
    }



El menu lo muestro en un archivo que luego mando a llamar en el index
No consigo crear los submenús con sus propios submenús anidados de
manera ilimitada, solo los de primer nivel, basado en el código que muestro
como podría solucionarlo, soy muy novato en estas cuestiones agradecería
me pudieran ayudar por favor, ya que las soluciones que he visto no me
han servido de mucho de antemano muchas gracias.


Pero cual es el problema??? porque no describis ningun problema...

Lo único que veo en esta pregunta son gritos y más gritos. Vaya manera de pedir ayuda, gritándole a la gente!! Las negritas deberían usarse para resaltar algún término concreto, no para escribir con ellas de normal, pues su uso sostenido aparte de que resulta incómodo a la hora de leer y puede provocar problemas, tiene la connotación de estar gritando para mucha gente. La gramática y el correcto uso de la escritura es importante para comunicarse de manera efectiva y que se pueda entender la pregunta de manera más sencilla.
